# How can I search , replace + increment in a html file?

Tags: search, replace, increment

I have 1,000 html pages. And a js script.

In the java code in the page I have somewhere "$ item_id = 1".

In every page I must change the id. I mean, in **page_2.html** I must have **"$ item_id = 2"** in the **page_3.html** I must have **"$ item_id = 3"** ... etc

I check more TextCrawlers softwares, but it offers me only search and replace, without incremental option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution. First, replace in all your files all `"$ item_id = 1"`, `"$ item_id = 2"` .. etc, with `"$ item_id = wxyz"` Then run the php script below in localhost, in the folder you keep the html files. You can name it `replace_increment.php`

```
<?php
$to_be_replaced = 'wxyz'; // exactly what it wants replaced
$nr_start = 1; // from which no start counting
$path_files = getcwd();
// echo $path_files;
$excluded_files = array(
    '.htaccess',
    'robots.txt',
    '.ftpquota',
    'search.html',
    'replace_increment.php',
);

$file_list = get_list_dir($path_files, false, 'file', true, $excluded_files);
if ( is_array($file_list) && count($file_list)) {
    // sort list files
    natsort($file_list);
    //echo '<pre>'.var_export($file_list,1).'</pre>';
    foreach($file_list as $file) {
        $original_content = file_get_contents($file);
        // Search the file for the replacement piece
        if ( stristr($original_content, $to_be_replaced) ) {
            // if found, replaces
            $content_modified = str_replace($to_be_replaced, $nr_start, $original_content);
            // remove the blank lines
            $content_modified = str_replace("\n\n\n\n", "\n\n", $content_modified);
            // save the file contents back
            $is_saved = file_put_contents($file, $content_modified);
            if ( ! $is_saved ) {
                die('Error: Unable to modify the file '.$file.'. I stayed at number '.$nr_start);
            }
            $nr_start++;
        }
    }
    echo 'They were checked '.count($file_list).' files and the last number is '.($nr_start - 1);
} else {
    echo 'Files Not found, check the file path';
}

function get_list_dir($path, $depth = false, $type = 'all', $inc = true, $exclude = array(), $max=95) {
    // Set list
    $list = array();
    // directory element is determined depending on the operating system
    $elm = ( stristr(PHP_OS, 'win') === false ) ? '/' : '\\';
    if (empty($path))
        return false;
    if (!is_dir($path))
        return false;
    // memorizes the current path
    $base_path = getcwd();
    // change to the path specified
    if ($base_path != $path) {
        $is_changed = chdir($path);
        if (!$is_changed)
            return false;
    }
    $required_path = getcwd();
    if (!$required_path)
        return false;
    // read path required
    $director = opendir($required_path);
    if (!$director) {
        // return to the base path
        chdir($base_path);
        return false;
    }
    // reads the current directory
    $read = readdir($director);
    if ($read === false) {
        // return to the base path
        chdir($base_path);
        return false;
    }
    while ($read) {
        // excluding files / directories unwanted
        if (!in_array($read, $exclude)) {
            // check what type is required
            switch ($type) {
                default:
                case 'all': // returns all files and directories found
                    // to memorize what is currently
                    $list[] = ( $inc ) ? $required_path . $elm . $read : $read;
                    // if is director and requires completion
                    if (is_dir($read) && $depth) {
                        if ( $max<1) {
                            $list[] = 'Too many subdirectories, indexing interrupted.';
                            break;
                        } else {
                            // browse the directory
                            $x = get_list_dir($read, $depth, $type, $inc, $exclude, $max-1);
                            $list = array_merge($list,$x);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 'dir': // only returns the list of directories found
                    // if is director
                    if (is_dir($read)) {
                        // to memorize what is currently
                        $list[] = ( $inc ) ? $required_path . $elm . $read : $read;
                        // if requires completion
                        if ($depth) {
                            if ( $max<1) {
                                $list[] = 'Too many subdirectories, indexing interrupted.';
                                break;
                            } else {
                                // browse the directory
                                $x = get_list_dir($read, $depth, $type, $inc, $exclude, $max-1);
                                $list = array_merge($list,$x);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 'file': // only returns the list of files found
                    // check if file
                    if (is_file($read)) {
                        // to memorize what is currently
                        $list[] = ( $inc ) ? $required_path . $elm . $read : $read;
                    }
                    // else if is folder and it requires completion
                    elseif ($depth) {
                        if ( $max<1) {
                            $list[] = 'Too many subdirectories, indexing interrupted.';
                            break;
                        } else {                        
                            // browse the directory
                            $x = get_list_dir($read, $depth, $type, $inc, $exclude, $max-1);
                            $list = array_merge($list,$x);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            } // end switch 
        } // end exclude
        // go to next
        $read = readdir($director);
    } // end while
    // director closes
    closedir($director);
    // returns to the initial path
    chdir($base_path);
    // return
    return $list;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a small script in the scripting language of your choice:

- retrieve the filenames of the HTML files in your directory
- for each filename:

  - parse the filename to extract the id into some variable `id`, e.g. via `/page_(\d+)\.html/` ([example](https://regex101.com/r/oX3qJ8/1))
  - read the file
  - search your term `"$ item_id = 1"` e.g. via `/\$ item_id = (\d+)/` ([example](https://regex101.com/r/mS1yT1/1))
  - replace the match with the string from the variable `id`
  - write file

Comment: hello. It's not about C++ or jave. It's about a simple search and replace, but with increment. Something like I have to find "xxx" in many pages and to replace with increment, like so : "xxx-1", "xxx-2", ...etc

How do I use regex?

Comment: If "it's not about C++ or java", is it maybe about your text editor? You would need a powerful editor like Emacs to perform this task. I could probably do it with a clever arranged Emacs kbd macro, using dir-ed and calculator modes. If you have no experience with Emacs, it is probably easier to teach you how to script your task.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small program with the basic idea of hardcode or dynamically.
So you define a number of pages (example works for same name).

You take a for-loop and use it like (in C#):

```
using System.IO;   
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

---

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
      {
        File.WriteAllText("Path\\page_" + i + ".html", Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("Path\\page_" + i + ".html"), @"\$ item_id = 1", "$ item_id = " + i));
      }
```

In the case you have different file names, you would need to use regex to get the correct number and use a for-each loop through a list with the filenames in it.